# Higher order matrix multiplication

Tags: algorithm, multiprocessing, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to do matrix multiplication in C using multiple processes with each of the child process is computing one row of the matrix . But if it is of order of say 200 then there will be 200 processes which would be inefficient for 2 3 CPUs. If I want to keep number of processes to 10 or 12 , how can I proceed with the same . Will there be any change in computation order ?

Comment: What programming language are you using? In C# for example you can easily run a parallel for loop with a specified degree of parallelism

Comment: If you are interesting in boosting performance, splitting up the computation by row of output is not a good idea. You should read up on [locality of reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference). Also, a web search for _"parallel matrix multiplication locality of reference"_ turns up lots of good material.

Answer (score 1):

One way to exploit multiple processes in matrix multiplication is to start with a recursive algorithm. For example, the [Strassen algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) recursively breaks the problem down into smaller and smaller multiplications which can be offloaded to any number of processors. In addition, normal matrix multiplication is of order O(N^3), but the Strassen algorithm can bring this down to O(N^2.8) which can be substantial for larger matrices.

*Note*: Usually higher-order refers to extended terms in a series expansion, more terms in a polynomial, etc. and typically not the size of a square matrix.